# Providing delay between events in UiAutomator Android

Tags: java, android, ui-automation, android-uiautomator

How can I provide delay between event clicks in UiAutomator Android.

First event is entering a url in EditText :

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Search here")).setText("abc.com");
getUiDevice.waitForIdle(15000);
```

Here I am loading a webpage inside a webview. So when url loading finishes , then I need to check for second event.

Second event is checking content description of a object :

```
UiObject curClass = new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.RelativeLayout"));  
UiObject yCur = curClass.getChild(new UiSelector().description("ye"));
getCurCol();

public void getCurCol() throws UiObjectNotFoundException {
try {
    if (yCur.getContentDescription() != null)
        report.append("Success");
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.err.println("\nCaught Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working.

I just want the app to wait for some time before checking for the second event.

I know these three methods are provided for delay in UI Automator -

```
public void waitForIdle(long timeout)

public void waitForIdle()

public boolean waitForWindowUpdate(String packageName, long timeout)
```

But I don't know how to use these methods.

Please suggest me a example how to use these.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try just

```
sleep(5000);
```

Let me know whether it works. Or you can try WaitForIdle( ) method.

Comment: Wait for idle will wait for the screen to turn off.

Answer (score 6):

If you need a wait after pressing a button

```
 UiObject settingsButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().text("Settings"));
        settingsButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

or

```
settingsButton.waitUntilGone(1000);
```

In case of launching new activity from **intent** this way is the easiest I could find to wait for a **settings package** appear:

```
mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg("com.android.settings").depth(0)), 2000);
UiObject settingsValidation = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().packageName("com.android.settings").text("Settings"));
        assertTrue("Unable to detect Settings", settingsValidation.waitForExists(4000));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
public boolean waitForWindowUpdate(null, long timeout)
```

Works good for me. I think it's possible to bring any 'not existing' `String packagaName`, for ex. `"blablabla"`, because you can get `null` instead of `String packageName`.

I've create a simply method to make a delay:

```
public void waitTime(int time) {
    getUiDevice().waitForWindowUpdate(null, time);
}
```

Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

`UiDevice` provides a few methods that may work for you:

```
public void waitForIdle(long timeout)

public void waitForIdle()

public boolean waitForWindowUpdate(String packageName, long timeout)
```

Comment: This didn't work out . I provided enough timeout still it isn't putting any delay between two clicks of events.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert in UIautomator, but this can be done with Thread.sleep().

Comment: Uiautomator doesn't work well with threads. That could work in certain situations, but not for a pause.

Comment: Not that I disagree, but the accepted answer also used `Thread.sleep()`

Answer (score 1):

i think `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(val);` should be helpful here

for instance

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

private void waitFor(long val)
{
         try
        {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(val);
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

I had a case where I had to wait for the Smart Lock dialog and find a way to dismiss it.

I ended up doing the following

```
final UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
        // Wait for the Smart Lock dialog to popup
        if(mDevice.waitForWindowUpdate(null, 5000)) {
            if("com.google.android.gms".equals(mDevice.getCurrentPackageName())) {
                // Dismiss dialog
                mDevice.pressBack();
            }
        }
```

This will wait for the dialog to appear and *if* it does it gets dismissed.

Answer (score 0):

```
webView.loadUrl("http://abc.com");
     webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
                webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

                    @Override
                    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);


                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
    //Handle your code here
                        //Toast.makeText(TableContentsWithDisplay.this, "Width " + view.getWidth() +" *** " + "Height " + view.getHeight(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view,
                            SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
                        //Toast.makeText(TableContentsWithDisplay.this, "error "+error, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

Load your url then there is method onPageFinished() where you can handle your code.

Comment: Hey , I am running testing code outside of app code as a blackbox tester. So I want some UiAutomator method to provide delay between [1] and [2] -> setText and function call -                                                  [1] new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Search here")) .setText("www.hotels.com");
                                                                  [2] check_currency();                                                    Can you provide some suggestion here.

Comment: I used it like this but still doesn't seem to be working.I want to provide delay between my click and function call -         new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Search or type URL"))
    .setText("ftd");
  getUiDevice().click(308 , 439);
  getUiDevice().waitForIdle(50);
  check_abc();

Comment: Please can someone suggest me any method here for providing delay. It's very important. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The only way I was able to add delay in UIAutomator code was in a similar way to slott 's answer:

I basically lunched a small app (the basic app from android examples) and pressed back to close it. This allows time for all elements to load properly.

```
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    final Intent intent = context.getPackageManager()
            .getLaunchIntentForPackage(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);    // Clear out any previous instances
    context.startActivity(intent);

    // Wait for the app to appear
    mDevice.wait(Until.hasObject(By.pkg(BASIC_SAMPLE_PACKAGE).depth(0)), LAUNCH_TIMEOUT);
    //then close this small app
    mDevice.pressBack();
```